# Opening music file in caja opens VLC as superuser

Tags: permissions, video, sudo, vlc

Running Ubuntu-Mate 4.18.0-16-generic
Using Caja, when I double click on an mp4 to play some music, the mp4 opens in VLC, and the window tile shows a vlc-icon-image, and then the text "(as superuser)".

Installed using sudo apt install VLC, checked /etc/sudoers, etc groups, shadow and passwd. Nothing out of order. I am a single user with sudo privileges.
So how is VLC being run as a superuser?

Running vlc at the command line gives [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Q63sLcuq)

Any explanations or directions on how to investigate would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you installed VLC? Please add output of `apt-cache policy vlc`, `snap list | grep vlc` and `which vlc` to the question. It may be installed as snap.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/t2YeP0Et

Comment: @ Finch you can transform your comment to answer and accept it to help other users.

Answer (score 0):

A very odd problem, indeed. After investigating the code results pertaining to firejail --debug, I installed it (yesterday), I attempted to remove restrictions with firecfg, and discovered that I had no sudo privileges whatsoever to do ANYTHING. I uninstalled firejail, and successfully had privileges returned to the console. VLC now fires up as a regular user. I then reinstalled firejail, only to discover vlc is still a regular user upon startup, but my firefox now opens as a superuser. The problem is firejail, and Id say the original question/problem has been resolved. Thanks N0rbert.